# Facebook integration gives error as Sorry an unexpected error occurred.Please try again

Tags: ios, facebook

Code:

```
 FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];

    [login logInWithReadPermissions: @[@"public_profile"]

     handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
         if (error) {
             NSLog(@"Process error");
         } else if (result.isCancelled) {
             NSLog(@"Cancelled");
         } else {
             NSLog(@"result:%@", result);

             if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
                 [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields": @"id, name, first_name, last_name, birthday, picture, email"}]
                  startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                      if (!error) {
                          NSLog(@"fetched user:%@", result);



                      }
                  }];
             }
             NSLog(@"Logged in");
         }
     }];
```

I am integrating facebook login.suddenly It gives error as Sorry an unexpected error occurred.Please try again Error code:-994.what is wrong with my code?any help will be appreciated.thanks in advnce

Comment: Did you intialize your fb SDK in app delegate?

Comment: Should have read the docs before you post here.

Answer (score 0):

follow the following link that will help you.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/#next